# If ports are unpriviledged, why can't I access them if I am root in a namespace?

Tags: namespace, port, network-namespaces, unshare

I've run `sudo sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_unprivileged_port_start=1`. However, `sudo ip netns exec myvpn unshare -r python -m http.server -b 127.0.0.1 2` does not work. Strangely enough, this does: `sudo ip netns exec myvpn unshare python -m http.server -b 127.0.0.1 2`. Why?

**EDIT**: However, both `sudo ip netns exec myvpn sudo -u $USER unshare python -m http.server -b 127.0.0.1 2` and `sudo ip netns exec myvpn sudo -u system unshare -r python -m http.server -b 127.0.0.1 2` don't work.

Answer (score 1):

[This](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/networking/ip-sysctl.txt) states that `ip_unprivileged_port_start` is a "per-namespace sysctl". So, just `sudo ip netns exec myvpn sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_unprivileged_port_start=1` and you're done.